# Django inline admin problems

Tags: python, django, models, admin

I'm trying to do such a thing: I have two models, connected via Foreign Key, and every instance of first model needs to be linked with **exactly** 4 instances of second (I use InlineAdmin to create them at the same time using extra=4 and max_num=4).

There are two problems:

1 - I need each of four models to has it's own default read only value for one of it's fields, this value needs to be selected from the field's choices option. But I need them to be **read only** (I know about readonly_fields, but it's useless for that. Javascript don't seems to be a good solution...

2 - I need to specify default values for some field for all four models at the same time editing only one field. I'm thinking of two possible solutions: javascript or one additional, **"fifth"** model with all hidden fields except the one I need so I can override *save()* to use it's values for other models and delete it.

But which is the right way?

Comment: Your question is not very clear.
What I get is:

You need something to be read only but you need it to be selected from choices option?

"Default values for all four models at the same time editing only one field" what does that mean?

What's the exact problem from users' perspective you are trying to solve?

Comment: 1 - I need each of four models to use predefined value for one of it's fields, it's a set of similar parameters, but each has it's own type.
2 - I need fields for all four models to auto-define while changing only one field, which defines all of them

Answer (score 0):

Try this documentation, it might help:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#editable